# Do I get the same optimizations if I deploy my Next.js to Cloudflare vs. Vercel?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've deployed most of my Next.js apps on vercel. Super clear, 10/10 experience.

I saw that Cloudflare is a lot cheaper when it comes to to deploying apps, and I was wondering if you get the same "benefits" on Cloudflare that come out of the box with Next.js like  component, caching data when performing fetch requests, etc.

Or, do they optimize things when you deploy on Vercel?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I've seen https://www.sentry.io integrates with Vercel deployments, so you might prefer going there.